# CURL in payment page

Tags: php, curl, google-analytics

In my secure payment page, I call a callback function in my controller, and I would call a Google Adsense code to track the payments.

So in static, when I use the code below in for example http://www.mywebsite.com/mycurlcode.php, that works, I see one visitor in the "real time" section of Google Analytics.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/analyticcode.php/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But when I put this code in the secure payment fonction callback(), I never have any visitor in tue "real time" section of GA...

Comment: Why can't you use javascript to call Google analytics?

Comment: If I call the Javascript that's not working, I never have a visitor :/...

Comment: Google Analytics has a very robust JavaScript API. See https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080 for information on how to initialize JavaScript tracking. You should be able to use JavaScript to track user purchases/payments. Is that not working for you?

Comment: Yes I'm using this, but in the HTTPS page, in the callback I don't know why I just can put MVC PHP code..